# How to detect and remove those complex emoji?

Tags: python, emoji

```
Fish Market
```

My code has a problem in parsing this string. I want to detect the emojis and remove them before they are processed by the sentence. So for the sentence, it should end up with:

```
Fish Market
```

I already used this emoji library:
https://pypi.org/project/emoji/

It can detect a lot of emojis, but not those appearing in this string. How to deal with it? I am not familiar with unicode.

Comment: Those are Egyptian hieroglyphs, not emoji.

Comment: Instead of "rejecting emoji", "accept ...". Unicode is divided into character classes, so accepting only the 'useful' set of such..

Comment: @user2864740 Would you please write a full answer for it? What do you mean by accepting them? An example would be very useful!

Comment: @ling It means that if you work with a blacklist there might be some character popping up later that you didn't consider. But if you work with a whitelist you only get what you find acceptable. So parse your text and remove anything that is not a letter, a number, a space or whatever character you accept. Parse the bytes (not characters) and maybe only keep bytes with an ascii code between 32 and 126 (see http://www.asciitable.com/ ) ?